# Docker build cannot find file that is

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I am trying to create an image where I install Intel MPI runtime.
I set the WORKDIR and I have the .tgz file incompressed in that folder.
But I am unable to run the install.sh

When the docker build fails, it still creates an image. I can run a container off of that image and I can manually install using the same command. But this command fails during docker build and I cannot figure out why.

-Sachin

My Dockerfile:

```
[root@curly sachin_docker]# cat Dockerfile
FROM  centos:7
RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash dumuser
ADD l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199.tgz /home/dumuser
WORKDIR /home/dumuser/l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199
RUN "./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu"
USER dumuser
[root@curly sachin_docker]#
```

Output:

```
> [root@curly sachin_docker]# docker build -t mympi_test . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  47.53MB 
Step 1/6 : FROM  centos:7  
  ---> 2d194b392dd1 
Step 2/6 : RUN useradd --create-home -s /bin/bash dumuser
  ---> Using cache  
  ---> a5b06d51c8c3 
Step 3/6 : ADD l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199.tgz /home/dumuser  
  ---> 1bfd6a2744f0 
Step 4/6 : WORKDIR /home/dumuser/l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199 
Removing intermediate container 3e599f1454c8  
  ---> 44e5b5eed7b8 
Step 5/6 : RUN "./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu"  
  ---> Running in 2e8fc1017095 
/bin/sh: ./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu: No such file or directory 
The command '/bin/sh -c "./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu"' returned a non-zero code: 127 [root@curly sachin_docker]#
```

When I run the container off that image I can manually run the install with the same command:

```
[root@curly sachin_docker]# docker run --rm -ti 44e5b5eed7b8 bash
[root@6dfc30bbb006 l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199]# /bin/sh -c  "./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu" 
[root@6dfc30bbb006 l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199]# ls /opt/intel bin                     
compilers_and_libraries_2018        documentation_2018 
parallel_studio_xe_2018        samples_2018 compilers_and_libraries 
compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199  impi               
parallel_studio_xe_2018.2.046  uninstall 
[root@6dfc30bbb006 l_mpi-rt_2018.2.199]#
```

Comment: My docker version:[root@curly sachin_docker]# docker version
Client:  
 Version:       18.03.0-ce-rc3  
 API version:   1.37  
 Go version:    go1.9.4  
 Git commit:    e730959  
 Built: Thu Mar  8 20:13:20 2018  
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64  
 Experimental:  false  
 Orchestrator:  swarm    
    
  Server:  
 Engine:  
  Version:      18.03.0-ce-rc3  
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)  
  Go version:   go1.9.4  
  Git commit:   e730959  
  Built:        Thu Mar  8 20:16:59 2018  
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64  
  Experimental: false  
[root@curly sachin_docker]#

Comment: I tried replacing the last 'RUN' command with 'ONBUILD' (though I don't have a subsequent Dockerfile to run after this one). This does not generate and error when I build the image. But it does not seem to run the command and create /opt/intel folder either (verified after running a container from the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is due to the fact that you have included *quotes* in the following directive in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN "./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu"
```

Because you have included quotes, this entire string is getting evaluated as the command you want to run. Basically, what's happening is the following:

```
/bin/bash -c "\"./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu\""
```

Similarly, if you try to run this command with quotes in an interactive shell, you'll get a similar error:

```
$ "./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu"
bash: ./install.sh --user-mode --silent ./silent.cfg --ignore-cpu: No such file or directory
```

**Remove the quotes** and it will treat `./install.sh` as the command and the rest of the string as the arguments to pass in.